# MonoTouch: UISegmentedControl in a MonoTouch.Dialog header?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uisegmentedcontrol, monotouch.dialog

How can I put a `UISegmentedControl` in a MonoTouch.Dialog header section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can manipulate the HeaderView member of the Section class just as you would any regular UIView:

```
public class SegmentedSection : Section
{
    UISegmentedControl _SegmentedControl;

    public SegmentedSection()
        : base("")
    {
        InitializeSection();
    }

    private void InitializeSection()
    {
        _SegmentedControl = new UISegmentedControl();

        // initialize _SegmenentedControl here...
        // make sure to set Frame appropriate relative to HeaderView bounds.

        this.HeaderView.AddSubview(_SegmentedControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: lol i was wondering why it didn't show up. always handy to add segments to it when you want to see something show up... #doh